# Running Flutter on Windows

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter

After getting Flutter on Windows, when I run flutter doctor the following error is coming

Got TLS error trying to find package archive at https://pub.dartlang.org.
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds...

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the "cache" folder in your Flutter "bin" folder. I had a similar issue with updating Flutter and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by removing my current flutter folder and by cloning flutter from the "master" branch.

`git clone -b master https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git`

After that, you can run `flutter doctor` normally.

**Note: Make sure your antivirus and firewall are disabled**

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing the same error, then I deleted flutter from my computer and I installed it from Android Studio. After then, The Installation was Successful. Try this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling any antivirus.it worked for me.